# Add timer and set size to viewpager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, slider

1. I have viewpager in my main activity and i need set timer to it to
   automatically change slide .
2. I need set defult size and position to my image ( any resolution) for any screen to show one third of my top screen like this [Preview](http://i57.tinypic.com/10ztum0.jpg).

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Image slide show 

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

         // End Image slide show


}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.gallery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For timer,
   in the main activity add these after viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

```
myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
pagerAdapter.setTimer(myPager,7);
```

in the pager adapter class

```
//gloabals
final Handler handler = new Handler();
public Timer swipeTimer ;


 /** 
 *  this function swipes pages left to right for every 7 seconds
 * @param myPager its viewpager.
 * @param time as second, for 7 second enter 7
 *
 */
public void setTimer(final ViewPager myPager, int time){
     final int size =objects.size();


        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            int NUM_PAGES =size;
            int currentPage = 0 ;
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES ) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, time*1000);
}
```

or you can use this one

```
/**
 * this function swipes pages left to right for every 7 seconds
 * @param myPager
 * @param time
 * @param numPages we recommend that it should be as much as much objects.size()
 * @param curPage we recommend that it should start from 0
 * 
 */
public void setTimer(final ViewPager myPager, int time, final int numPages, final int curPage){

        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            int NUM_PAGES =numPages;
            int currentPage = curPage ;
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES ) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 1000, time*1000);

}
```

this is for stopping timer

```
 /**
 * its kills runnable
 */
public void stopTimer(){
    //handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    swipeTimer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I don't get what the " final int size =objects.size(); " is in setTimer ??

Comment: its size of objects my pager use.you can image them as images . lets say that final int size =3; or you can say final int size =GalImages.length;

Comment: thanks , the second solution worked for me , but i need repetitive slide show ,  i think for this one i need Initialized NUM_PAGES and currentPage , but where and how Initialized NUM_PAGES and currentPAge ?

Comment: if you got 7 images in your slide, you will give number of pages (NUM_PAGES) as 7 and if you like to start from 3, give current page 3 , so it will go as like 3-4-5-6-7 and goes 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.i would suggest that you should initialize your images in contractor as you did. _ImageAdapter(Context context, int[] GalImages){
        this.context=context;
        this.GalImages=GalImages.
    }_ and your number of pages = GalImages.lenght. it more of generic use.

Comment: Thanks alp, but how would we slow the quick transition effects of viewpager?